# python: How to assign a class function result to a class variable in the same class

Tags: python, member-functions, class-variables

I am a beginner to python and want to understand the python class modules and class variables.

I just want to assign a class function's return value to the class variable.
I tried in different ways, are these valid in python?

Sample code:

```
class Example():
    def class_member(self):
        dict_1 = {'k1' : 'v1','k2' : 'v2'}
        return dict_1

    class_var = class_member()
    print(class_var)

x_obj =  Example()
```

Errors:

```
    class_var = class_member()
TypeError: class_member() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

    class_var = class_member(self)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined

    class_var = Example.class_member()
NameError: name 'Example' is not defined
```

Comment: You should include your class and the full error to get a exhaustive answer.

Comment: I think what you’re looking for is an `__init__` method that will do `self.var = self.method()`.

Comment: `class_var=x_obj.class_member()` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to store variable inside a class, You might need an initialization function `__init__` with double underscores on opposite sides. And you will need a `self` in front of the 'class_var'. Which will mean that the variable has become part of the class. And also you will need a `self` in front of the 'class_member' function. Which will mean that the function belongs to this class.

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.class_member()

    def class_member(self):
        dict_1 = {'k1' : 'v1','k2' : 'v2'}
        self.class_var = dict_1
```

```
e = Example()
```

```
print(e.class_var) #prints {'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this is to make dict_1 property of the Example class and then return it in the class_member function.

```
class Example():
  dict_1 = {'k1' : 'v1','k2' : 'v2'}
  def class_member(self):
    return self.dict_1

example = Example()

print(example.dict_1) # prints {'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2'}
print(example.class_member()) # prints {'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2'}
```

I would recommend to go through this [link](https://pythontips.com/2013/08/07/the-self-variable-in-python-explained/) and read it in detail.